# How can I convert an int64 into a byte array in go?

Tags: go, casting

I have an id that is represented at an `int64`.  How can I convert this to a `[]byte`?  I see that the binary package does this for uints, but I want to make sure I don't break negative numbers.

Comment: in short: `int` or `uint` is just how CPU *"interprets"* the underlying bits. The underlying bits(11100101...) in the memory remain the same. If it's `uint`, the interpreting is straightforward. But if it's `int`, there are several ways to interpret/represent negative numbers from/to bits (two's complement is a popular way).

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Converting between `int64` and `uint64` doesn't change the sign bit, only the way it's interpreted.

You can use `Uint64` and `PutUint64` with the correct [`ByteOrder`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary/#ByteOrder)

http://play.golang.org/p/wN3ZlB40wH

```
i := int64(-123456789)

fmt.Println(i)

b := make([]byte, 8)
binary.LittleEndian.PutUint64(b, uint64(i))

fmt.Println(b)

i = int64(binary.LittleEndian.Uint64(b))
fmt.Println(i)
```

output:

```
-123456789
[235 50 164 248 255 255 255 255]
-123456789
```

Comment: Hi, should i use the constants `MaxVarintLenXX` to determine the size of buffer before put ?

Comment: No, `PutUint64` uses fixed length encoding. You only need `MaxVarintLenXX` when using `PutVarint`.

Answer (score 8):

If you don't care about the sign or endianness (for example, reasons like hashing keys for maps etc), you can simply shift bits, then AND them with 0b11111111 (0xFF):

(assume v is an int32)

```
b := [4]byte{
        byte(0xff & v),
        byte(0xff & (v >> 8)),
        byte(0xff & (v >> 16)),
        byte(0xff & (v >> 24))}
```

(for int64/uint64, you'd need to have a byte slice of length 8)

Comment: I have slice of 6 bytes... is that possible? And I need timestamp from that... [224, 221, 199, 147, 195, 47] should get to 1632933900000

Comment: @ahmet, why do we need a byte slice of length 8 ? why not just 4 ?

Comment: @Gru, because an `int64`/`uint64` uses 8 Bytes of storage. `int32`/`uint32` only uses 4 Bytes.

Comment: Why do you need to AND with 0xFF?

Answer (score 6):

The code:

```
var num int64 = -123456789

// convert int64 to []byte
buf := make([]byte, binary.MaxVarintLen64)
n := binary.PutVarint(buf, num)
b := buf[:n]

// convert []byte to int64
x, n := binary.Varint(b)
fmt.Printf("x is: %v, n is: %v\n", x, n)
```

outputs

```
x is: -123456789, n is: 4
```

Comment: what is the b := buf[:n] line for?

Comment: @JohnBalvinArias: it's because this example uses a variable length encoding

Answer (score 6):

You can use this too:

```
var num int64 = -123456789

b := []byte(strconv.FormatInt(num, 10))

fmt.Printf("num is: %v, in string is: %s", b, string(b))
```

Output:

```
num is: [45 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57], in string is: -123456789
```

Comment: This can produce substantially more than 8 bytes, and the bytes are using all their bits for data.

Answer (score 3):

If you need a similar function as `int.to_bytes(length, byteorder, *, signed=False)` in Go you can do this:

```golang
func uint64ToLenBytes(v uint64, l int) (b []byte) {
    b = make([]byte, l)

    for i := 0; i < l; i++ {
        f := 8 * i
        b[i] = byte(v >> f)
    }

    return
}

func int64ToLenBytes(v int64, l int) (b []byte) {
    return uint64ToLenBytes(uint64(v), l)
}
```

It will return a slice of bytes, for example:

```golang
ba = int64ToLenBytes(258, 3)
fmt.Printf("%#v\n", ba)

// output:
[]byte{0x2, 0x1, 0x0}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple function that should accomplish what you are wanting:

```golang
func Int64ToBytes(number int64) []byte {
    big := new(big.Int)
    big.SetInt64(number)
    return big.Bytes()
}
```

Comment: very inefficient answer

Comment: func Int64ToBytes(number int64) []byte {
    big := new(big.Int)
    return big.SetInt64(number).Bytes()
}